# What is the benefit of using complex numbers to store graph coordinates?

Tags: python, graph-theory, complex-numbers

I am looking at a [solution](https://github.com/hughcoleman/advent-of-code/blob/main/2022/12.py) to an [Advent of Code puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/12) that stores coordinates as complex numbers:

```
 heightmap = {
    complex(x, y): c
        for y, ln in enumerate(sys.stdin.read().strip().split("\n"))
        for x, c in enumerate(ln)
}
```

Then accesses them later as follows:

```
for xy, c in heightmap.items():
    for d in (1, -1, 1j, -1j):
        if ord(heightmap.get(xy + d, "{")) <= ord(c) + 1:
            G.add_edge(xy, xy + d)
```

I can see that this code makes the 'get neighbors' line easy to write/think about, but I don't see that it is worth the added complexity (no pun intended).

Can someone explain why it's useful to store the grid coordinates as complex numbers?

Comment: "I can see that this code makes the 'get neighbors' line easy to write/think about, but I don't see that it is worth the added complexity (no pun intended)." - apparently whoever wrote the code disagreed. That's all this really boils down to.

Comment: I thought there might be some other virtues I was not aware of.

Comment: What additional complexity? Complex numbers are nothing more than pairs of real numbers. Operations on complex numbers don't really depend on the exact interpretation of `1j**2 == -1`. Pairwise addition of the real and imaginary parts and distribution of multiplication over addition are useful no matter how you choose to interpret the results.

Comment: Consider what `xy + d` would need to look like if `xy` and `d` were simply tuples, or what an appropriate class that duplicates what `complex` already defines would look like.

Comment: @chepner Right, but the two-dimensional vector space of pairs of real numbers (ℝ²) suffices for that purpose. I find the question justified, though an appropriate answer might then simply be "complex numbers give us the benefits of ℝ² that we need".

Comment: The real question is: Why are they using `.split('\n')` instead of `.splitlines()`?

Comment: Exactly. There is no two-dimensional vector space of pairs of real numbers in Python. But there is `complex`. This boils down to whether one should use an existing type that's isomorphic to the one you  want/need, or define a specific isomorphic type to use instead. The latter is better, but the former is fine for something like an AoC submission.

Comment: @Stef Until your comment, I also somehow overlooked the existence of `str.splitlines`.

Comment: @chepner I think we're largely on the same page, and the syntactic convenience of `complex` is hard to beat. There is something else that noone has mentioned yet, namely that with the type `complex` one can do things like `abs(3 + 4j)` to compute the distance to the origin (here `5.0`).

Comment: @Stef The real real question is, why aren't they simply iterating over `sys.stdin`? :-) (That is, `for y, ln in enumerate(sys.stdin) for x, c in enumerate(ln.strip())`)

Comment: @LoverofStructure There is already `from math import norm` to compute the distance from the origin, and `from math import dist` for the distance between two tuples. Writing `abs` instead of `norm` doesn't really seem like an improvement. Being able to add two complexes with `+` on the other hand, is a huge improvement. Also scaling a complex by a real number, or rotating a complex by multiplication with `exp(i * theta)`.

Comment: @Stef I disagree partly: `abs` for `complex` is built-in and doesn't require any imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because it's easy/less to write and think about. Also means less opportunity for typos :-)

I've been doing that for years, ever since I saw someone else do that. Usually not even typing the deltas explicitly but *calculating* them. I.e., instead of

```
for d in (1, -1, 1j, -1j):
    use(z + d)
```

do:

```
for i in range(4):
    use(z + 1j**i)
```

Possible alternatives when using separate x and y variables:

```
for dx, dy in ((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)):
    use(x+dx, y+dy)
```

```
for x2, y2 in ((x+1, y), (x, y+1), (x-1, y), (x, y-1)):
    use(x2, y2)
```

Ermahgerd, so frustrating. I actually did make several typos while writing these :-)

(Tests at [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZHRCoIwFIbpdk9xLjfdQi0hhB7GmJZSKjph80mCbryph-ppOtOKYQ3GDof9__8dzu3RGHWqq3G89yoXu-fqOsAeNuBDXBLSYd1lijLSd5mt16mUJK9bkFBUQEMOAm9Y2rdkCQE8-JUOaCAZIWphoL4GhTVo0-qY0e1CGJaeV6C4aYtK0Y6D4oAkqMYm0RyMReQQ_wKe08tBpuANycxKBzbjokqaidlCB4wDDRDcvsJpiJA5MNq3OuNL82cUJ0q5UTpCSTRHaR-9jfWefKY4LdzeInDS_h99XtB7T599vQA))

Comment: Also, if `xy1 = x1 + y1 * 1j` and `xy2 = x2 + y2 * 1j`, then `xy1 + xy2 == (x1+x2) + (y1+y2)*1j`, whereas if `xy1 = (x1, y2)` and `xy2 = (x2, y2)` then `xy1 + xy2 == (x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

Comment: Also, complex numbers are super convenient if you need to perform rotations. The image of `z` by rotation of centre `c` and angle `t` is `c + exp(t * 1j) * (z - c)`. And for rotation by 90° you can just multiply by `1j` directly (which is what you did when you "calculated" your four directional vectors).

Comment: @Stef Well, yes, that (the "whereas" in your first comment) doesn't work at all, so nobody would even do that. I included two actual alternatives now for comparison.

Comment: Yes, my point is, you can add vectors with `+` if they are complex (or numpy arrays); but you need to write your own adding function if they are tuples (or use `tuple(map(add, (xy1, xy2)))` with `from operator import add`; or `(xy1[0] + xy2[0], xy1[1] + xy2[1])`)