# Iterate up, down, left and right through matrix

Tags: python-3.x, loops, map-directions

I have the following python code:

```
exploreIsland(grid, row-1, col, m, n)
exploreIsland(grid, row+1, col, m, n)
exploreIsland(grid, row, col-1, m, n)
exploreIsland(grid, row, col+1, m, n)
```

explaining:
`row` and `col` stands for the position of the `grid` of size `m`x`n` I'm currently in

the code snippet above goes up, down, left and right from the position of the `grid` I'm currently in

**my question is: how could I replace such four calls with a sigle function call inside a loop?**

---

<sub>I've tried to iterate through `range(1,4)` and change the sign based on `%2`... but that's not working. Aparently I can solve bigger programming problems, but not this simple one :|</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75793007/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-complex-numbers-to-store-graph-coordinates/75793298#75793298

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the link commented by @beaker, I've implemented the following loop:

```
for dx, dy in ((1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)):
    exploreIsland(grid, row+dx, col+dy, m, n)
```

and it worked!!!